# os.listdir showing deleted files

Tags: django, python-3.x

Using `os.listdir()` to get files of a folder and `os.remove()` to remove files from it and files are still listed after being removed until Django server is restarted. Is it any way to avoid having to restart the server to get the "correct" file list?

Have a file called `pics.py` with a `file_list` that is passed via `views.py` and rendered in a template. 
The error appear when running from browser, via eclipse the list is updated instantly.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, dirname, abspath

mypath = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))) + "\..\media\dump"

file_list = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
```

Comment: Show us your code. I'm guessing you're calling `os.listdir()` once, maybe outside a view function?

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this? It is hard to believe this happening in the first place, unless you are running into some kind of race condition.

Comment: If you "store" the list of files, then evidently it is *not* updated if you later modify your files.

Comment: Tried to reproduce a small example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to update `file_list` in your view function, e.g.

```py
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, dirname, abspath

def get_files():
  mypath = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))) + "\..\media\dump"
  return [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]

def my_view(request):
  return render(request, "template.html", {"files": get_files()})
```

(or the equivalent class-based view).